# Socket closes itself when sending a large amount of data?

Tags: java, android, sockets

Please help me understand sockets. I've been sending accelerometer data from Android through sockets to PC and after some time the data receiving stops, then after a while I get "Client closed connection".
Is it due to the disruption in the network and simply sockets aren't too reliable?

```
public class Connection {

    private String IP;
    private int port;
    private Socket socket;
    private PrintWriter output;

    public void connect(String IP, int port) {
        this.IP = IP;
        this.port = port;
        new Connect().execute();
    }

    public void sendText(String data) {
        new SendText().execute(data);
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        new Disconnect().execute();
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        if (socket != null)
            return socket.isConnected();
        else return false;
    }

    private class Connect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                socket = new Socket(IP, port);
                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                output = new PrintWriter(out);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class SendText extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            output.println(params[0]);
            output.flush();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class Disconnect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Part of Accelerometer class:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor mySensor = event.sensor;

        if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            float z = event.values[2];
            connection.sendText("x"+Float.toString(x)+"a");
            connection.sendText("y"+Float.toString(y)+"s");
            connection.sendText("z"+Float.toString(z)+"d");
        }
    }
```

Should I just detect by sending some "ping" and "pong" text to know when the connection is broken and then simply reconnect?

Or maybe it's better to just use some library like this one:
https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet

The application will be used for remote control of a small vehicle.

Comment: Think you could benefit from using some thread safety practices? You're calling `sendText` three times in a row there, each creating a new thread/task using the output stream.  Not sure if this could cause some problems.  maybe do a `synchronized (output) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You are using multiple asynctaskers with one single socket and this are causing the problems you have described .

You should implement one socket per asynctasker. Get rid of Connection and Disconnection asyncclasses and just implement "Connect" -> "SendText" -> "Disconnect" altogether inside doInBackground in a single asynctask class.

Or you should implement a queue and put all information into a row and implement a service to process that row by sending text using a single socket, like "Connect" -> "Process row's records" -> "Disconnect".

Comment: So should I have a static string in my Service and check in infinite loop in that Service whether that string is filled or not and then send data depending on that?

Comment: That is not the best way of doing a queue... I prefer use Collections.synchronizedList()... and while sensor events fill itens in, a service fills itens out... got it?